# different colors to p-rating in primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to color stars  and have more than one `p-rating` in .html and trying to apply different color to different `p-rating` in same component.

How to style stars using primeng or angular way.

## .html

```
<p-rating [ngModel]="inputData?.rating" readonly="true" stars="5"[cancel]="false" style="float: left;font-size: 35px !important;color: #4741fa!important;">
    </p-rating>
    <p-rating [ngModel]="inputData?.rating" readonly="true" stars="5"[cancel]="false" style="float: left;font-size: 35px !important;color: #000000!important;">
    </p-rating>
    <p-rating [ngModel]="inputData?.rating" readonly="true" stars="5"[cancel]="false" style="float: left;font-size: 35px !important;color: #4743fb!important;">
    </p-rating>
```

## .css

```
.ui-rating-icon {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    color: #ffab18 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

component part should be like this:

```
@Component({  
selector: 'app-view-product',
templateUrl: './view-product.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./view-product.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

you must add encapsulation to change style

Answer (score 0):

In primeng 9 you can use this attribute to bind style,

`[iconOnStyle]="{'color':'#4743fb'}"`